# cmake error: The following Boost libraries could not be found

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm using `cmake` and `boost` to make visual studio solution. 
my command is:

```
F:\C++\yapimpl\build>cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 11" -DBOOST_ROOT=E:\lib\lib\boost
_1_54_0 -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=E:\lib\lib\boost_1_54_0\bin\vc11\lib
```

though I've set `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` and `BOOST_ROOT`, it still says `boost_unit_test_framework`
 could not be found.

the directory `E:\lib\lib\boost_1_54_0\bin\vc11\lib` indeed contains these files:

```
08/08/2013  CSer 03:48        12,738,344 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-1
_54.lib
08/08/2013  CSer 03:44        31,489,264 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-g
d-1_54.lib
08/08/2013  CSer 04:10        14,109,766 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-s
-1_54.lib
08/08/2013  CSer 03:59        32,856,094 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-s
gd-1_54.lib
```

but seems those are not recognized. what's the problem?
the Traceback is here: http://codepad.org/zgL9tpjo

the project is here :
https://github.com/Answeror/yapimpl
and
https://github.com/Answeror/ACMake
hope someone could try cmake the `yapimpl` project

Comment: Can you run `cmake . -DBoost_DEBUG=ON -DBoost_DETAILED_FAILURE_MSG=ON` and paste the output here please?

Comment: Did you run the CMake command above?  I'd rather see the output of CMake with boost diagnostics switched on than try and configure yapimpl :-)

Comment: @Fraser the ouput is [here](http://codepad.org/F14e72UU)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As your library names all start with `lib`, it seems like you have built static versions of the boost libraries.  The [boost naming conventions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) state:

> **`lib`**
>
> *Prefix*: except on Microsoft Windows, every Boost library name begins with this string. On Windows, only ordinary static libraries use the `lib` prefix; import libraries and DLLs do not.

In the output generated by CMake, there is a line which states:

```
-- [ F:/C++/yapimpl/acmake/FindBoost.cmake:570 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = OFF
```

Also, you can see that the library names CMake is searching for don't start with `lib`:

```
... Searching for UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-1_54;...
```

To tell CMake to search for the static version of Boost, you just need to set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to `ON`.  You can do this in your CMakeLists.txt *before* calling `find_package(Boost ...)`:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
```

or you can just set it on the command line:

```
cmake . -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON
```

For more info on the `FindBoost` CMake module, see [the docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module:FindBoost), or run

```
cmake --help-module FindBoost
```

Comment: thx for your answer, in the [traceback](http://codepad.org/F14e72UU) i posted above, I do have `-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON`, but the output shows it becomes `OFF` later， could you check the projects ( https://github.com/Answeror/yapimpl and https://github.com/Answeror/ACMake)  to see what's happening?

Comment: There are a couple of places in that mountain of CMake code where `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` is set to `OFF` by default.  For the first one, can you try running `cmake . -DBOOST_SUPPORT_STATIC=ON` please?  Also, if you add `variable_watch(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS)` to the top of your own CMakeLists.txt, it should print a message each time the variable is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I only set BOOST_ROOT when using CMake and boost. Everything else works without any problems

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake" 
-G"Visual Studio 11 Win64" 
-HC:\USB\dev\MyProject -BC:\build\MyProject 
-DBOOST_ROOT="C:\USB\thirdparty\vs2012\boost_1_54_0-x64"
```

Comment: Do you mean `BOOST_ROOT`?  That's what you're setting in the above command.